# Possibilities to execute a groovy script with Hybris in java code (no hAC)

Tags: java, groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm wondering if there is a way to execute a groovy script with Hybris. I know how groovy scripts are executed with the Hybris Administration Console (hAC), but I need a solution to execute such a script from java code. Preferably with the Patching Framework's @SystemSetup but not necessary. (https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/5db22427a1d541669bc4d12793a7b672.html?locale=en-US)

I'm looking for a method similar to Impex import (eg. from core extension):

```
@SystemSetup(extension = SampleCoreConstants.EXTENSIONNAME)
public class CoreSystemSetup extends AbstractSystemSetup {

public static final String IMPORT_ACCESS_RIGHTS = "accessRights";

@SystemSetup(type = Type.ESSENTIAL, process = Process.ALL)
public void createEssentialData(final SystemSetupContext context)
{
    importImpexFile(context, "/samplecore/import/common/file-name.impex");
}

@Override
@SystemSetupParameterMethod
public List<SystemSetupParameter> getInitializationOptions()
{
    final List<SystemSetupParameter> params = new ArrayList<>();

    params.add(createBooleanSystemSetupParameter(IMPORT_ACCESS_RIGHTS, "Import Users & Groups", true));

    return params;
}
```

Here the same with SQL: https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/run-native-sql-query-hybris/

So anyone who can help me out with a solution (or with a clear answer if this is possible or not) are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: from java you can run groovy code.

Comment: The execution should be possible without any groovy tool like groovy shell or the groovy-all dependency.

Comment: You must have groovy dependency if it's not present in hybris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to run groovy in your code. Even in SystemSetup.

You can use the hybris service (spring bean) `de.hybris.platform.scripting.engine.ScriptingLanguagesService`
that's available in the `processing` extension

In the code, this could be something like

```
final ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("location.groovy");
final ResourceScriptContent content = new ResourceScriptContent(resource);

ScriptExecutable groovyScript = scriptingLanguagesService.getExecutableByContent(content);

ScriptExecutionResult result = groovyScript.execute();
```

This will execute a script on the given location in your classpath. If you don't have your groovy in a file in your classpath, there are other Content types possible. For example: SimpleScriptContent

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Do you know something like this with SQL? For example scriptingLanguagesService.getExecutableByContent(contentWithSQL);

Comment: Yes, there is a bean/class `HybrisJdbcTemplate`. With this bean you can execute sql queries => `template.execute`

Answer (score 1):

There are many to execute groovy script.

**WAY 1:**

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
 
final Resource resource = new FileSystemResource("/Users/zeus/scripts/setMimesForMedias.groovy");

// Let's assume we have scriptingLanguagesService injected by the Spring
final ScriptContent scriptContent = new ResourceScriptContent(resource);
final ScriptExecutable executable = scriptingLanguagesService.getExecutableByContent(scriptContent);
 
// now we can execute script
final ScriptExecutionResult result = executable.execute();
 
// to obtain result of execution 
System.out.println(result.getScriptResult());
```

**WAY 2 :**
We can use simple method as below to achieve.

Here is the sample code:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;



GroovyShell groovy = new GroovyShell(new Binding());
groovy.setVariable("text","Hello World!"); // you can variables here as many you needed
groovy.evaluate("println text"); // you can pass file as well instead of text
```

**WAY 3 :**
If you want the OOB one, **ScriptingJobPerformable** is the OOB class which you can take reference from that.

```
final ScriptExecutable executable = scriptingLanguagesService.getExecutableByURI(dynamicScriptingJob.getScriptURI());

    LOG.info("### Starting executing script : " + dynamicScriptingJob.getScriptURI() + " ###");
    final Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()//
                                                                             .put("cronjob", cronJob) //
                                                                             .put("log", LOG) //
                                                                             .build();
    final ScriptExecutionResult result = executable.execute(params);
```

Please refer [Scripting Engine](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/8bec04a386691014938a9996a977d07f.html) for detailed explanation